# preg_match in .bat file to flusk image url

Tags: windows, command-line

welcome,

I have problem with .bat script on windows.

I use wget to download html stats page, now i have to find (in html source) url like this

```
http://www.example.com/stats/367895.jpeg

The 367895 is a random generated number.
```

and download chart jpeg.

I think i can't do this in .bat, Do You know any external command line application what i could trigger from .bat and show in output finded url ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You could use grep for Windows:
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm

As a Windows built in, but much less powerful, alternative there is "find". But you cannot use regex then

Comment: Windows also has `findstr`, which supports regexes (similar to POSIX standard regex, but without `\|`)

Comment: Cool! I didn't know that.